# integrate d3-cloud with rollup (actually Svelte)

Tags: javascript, d3.js, rollupjs, svelte, svelte-3

I have the following Svelte 3 project using d3-cloud. I include it in index.html before the head end like this:

```
  <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://rawgit.com/jasondavies/d3-cloud/master/build/d3.layout.cloud.js"></script>
</head>
```

I'd like to remove any reference to it in my index.html and include it with npm, like this:

```
npm install npm i d3@3 d3-cloud
```

And this is what I get in my package.json

```
  "dependencies": {
    "d3": "^3.5.17",
    "d3-cloud": "^1.2.5",
    "sirv-cli": "^0.4.4"
  },
```

I have a js function that references d3 and d3.layout.cloud()

I tried commenting the reference to d3 in my index.html and then:

```
import * as d3 from 'd3'
import * as d3cloud from 'd3-cloud'
```

Nevetheless I still get this message from rollup:

```
(!) Missing exports
https://rollupjs.org/guide/en/#error-name-is-not-exported-by-module
src\lib\wordCloud.js
scale is not exported by node_modules\d3\index.js
20:   function __wordCloud(selector, width = 500, height = 500) {
21:
22:     const fill = d3.scale.category20();
                        ^
23:
24:     d3.select(selector).selectAll("*").remove();
src\lib\wordCloud.js
select is not exported by node_modules\d3\d3.js
25:   const fill = d3.scale.category20();
26:
27:   d3.select(selector).selectAll("*").remove();
         ^
28:
29:   //Construct the word cloud's SVG element
src\lib\wordCloud.js
layout is not exported by node_modules\d3\index.js
71:       // of the wordCloud return value.
72:       update: function(words) {
73:         d3.layout.cloud().size([width, height])
               ^
74:           .words(words)
75:           .padding(5)
src\lib\wordCloud.js
```

And when I run the code I get this error on the browser console:

```
TypeError: this is undefined d3.js:8:20
    d3 d3.js:8
    d3 d3.js:9554
    createCommonjsModule bundle.js:402
    app bundle.js:405
    <anonymous> bundle.js:10424
[...]
```

I also tried with adding this to my rollup.config.js, but I guess that it's not what I mean to do (I don't want to have it as a external resource, but bundled in my bundle.js)

```
[...]
    name: 'app',
    file: 'public/bundle.js',
    globals: { 'd3': 'd3' },
    external: ['d3']
  },
  plugins: [
[...]
```

I'd like to let rollup handle my frontend dependecies (like d3 and d3-cloud) and include them in my bundle.js (I still don't quite get how to work with bundlers for frontend dependcies)

How should I do it?

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: sorry, I added more information about the error

Comment: It looks like your html script tag src points to version 3 of `d3`. Whereas when you install using `npm i d3` it will install version *5*, which has a different api. You can try installing version 3 with `npm i d3@3` or upgrade your code to use version 5.

Comment: thanks a lot for your reply, I updated my project with d3@3 but it seems like I'm still getting the same error

Comment: I may be wrong, but it looks like you have `external` inside the output, it should be at the top level.